# AWS S3 cli not working with endpoint urls

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, wasabi

I am attempting to use wasabi but the aws s3 cli seams to ignore --enpoint-url when ever I specify s3://my-wasabi-bucket

For Example

```
aws s3 ls --endpoint-url=https://s3.wasabisys.com --profile wasabi
```

Will list my wasabi buckets, but when I do

```
aws s3 ls --endpoint-url=https://s3.wasabisys.com --profile wasabi s3://my-bucket
```

Where my-bucket is a bucket that was in the list from above, I get

```
Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://s3.us-central-1.amazonaws.com/my-bucket?list-type=2&prefix=&delimiter=%2F&encoding-type=url"
```

Comment: If you use `--debug`, does it contain any more information? As an experiment, I tried using that endpoint with AWS credentials (not Wasabi). It resulted in `AuthorizationHeaderMalformed` from Wasabi (I think), so the AWS CLI sent me to AWS instead. So, the debug info might show you want is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I was using the wrong endpoint url, my bucket is hosted in wasabi's central-1 so I needed to use --endpoint-url=https://s3.us-central-1.wasabisys.com